# capawesome app-update -> current version and available version formatting different (one includes "bundle version")

Tags: ios, plugins, version, store, capacitor

Trying to get capawesome/app-update to work correctly (https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-plugins/tree/main/packages/app-update)

Basic issue is that, at least for iOS, the plugin returns different strings for currentVersion vs availableVersion.  It seems currentVersion does not include the "bundle version" (ex: "1.0.0") but availableVersion does (ex: "1.0.0 (25)").  Since I would like to include the bundle version in the comparison but am not sure how to get at it via the plugin, or why it is inconsistent.

Code examples to get version info:

```
import {AppUpdate} from "@capawesome/capacitor-app-update";
...
await AppUpdate.getAppUpdateInfo().currentVersion
...
await AppUpdate.getAppUpdateInfo().availableVersion
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.
jason